# Python: How to create password digest and nonce for a SOAP request

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, nonce

I had the following header in a SOAP request (I replace the original base64 encoded values with `XXX` and `YYY`)

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="true">
        <wsse:UsernameToken
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-11">
            <wsse:Username>MrSoapNewbie</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">XXX</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">YYY</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2022-07-04T08:39:20.513Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

When I ran it, it was fine. A few mins later, it wasn't and I got the message:

```
The creation time is older than  currenttime - timestamp-freshness-limit - max-clock-skew
```

I amend the date and I get

```
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Invalid Security Header
```

My question is how do I generate the `password digest` and the `nonce` for a SOAP request using Python?

I'm trying to use [Zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) but getting:

```
Unparseable date
```

Where the date is

```
2022-07-04T09:26:36+00:00
```

Thanks